Fill mesh polys in Geometry Nodes

I have the above skeletal mesh with no duplicate vertices and I need to fill all the polygons (which are quads and tris only) using geometry nodes. Related questions on stackexchange (like q1, q2, q3) seem to be addressing different issue.
Simply converting the mesh to curves and using fill curves with polygon options gives a few separated edges and polys with more than 4 verts.


Is this always a 2D shape?

@MarkusvonBroady Yes, but it would be great if there is a generic solution.


Here is an alternative approach. Note:

The logic is basically to get the shortest path to the adjacent node excluding the current edge, so there could be some edge cases that don't pass the criteria in intended manner and there could be a more robust condition check to determine the right verts within the generated poly.
This will create many redundant polys which are got rid of with merge distance in the end, maybe there can be some more selection criteria added to Edge Cost to restrict the generated poly count
This uses just one repeat zone and takes care of polys with any vert count

Thoughts and suggestions are welcome.


I was thinking about shortest path too :) should be much faster than mine and support any n-gon.

Generalized 3D triangle fill
In 3D space the only reasonable logic I could figure behind filling triangles is to create triangles based on loops of 3 connected triangles. The algorithm then becomes:

For each vertex v0:

iterate over all of its edges e0:

for each edge e0 find the other vertex v1;
iterate over all v1 edges e1:

for each edge e1 find the other vertex v2;
iterate over all v2 edges e2:

for each edge e2 find the other vertex v3;
check if v0 and v3 are the same vertex
if so, v0 (v3), v1 and v2 form a triangle









Python equivalent:
for v0 in verts:  # red
    for e0 in v0.link_edges:  # green
        v1 = e0.other_vert(v0)
        for e1 in v1.link_edges:  # blue
            v2 = e1.other_vert(v1)
            for e2 in v2.link_edges:  # orange
                v3 = e2.other_vert(v2)
                if v0 == v3:
                    add_triangle(v0, v1, v2)

Time for geonodes:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
Test:
 
Imgur mirror left  ||  Imgur mirror right
Remarks:

It tries not to avoid creating overlapping triangles; in Python you could mark already processed vertices and edges (not sure about the logic in 3D space though), but in geonodes it would make it slower not faster.
It creates 600% overlapping triangles, because each triangle can start its formation from 3 places, and from there go in 2 directions; just apply "Merge by Distance" on the output.
Again, in Python you could limit yourself to only follow vertices in increasing index order (wouldn't work for quads) and maybe find similar ways to break early, but in geonodes this would only make it slower...
It's still terribly slow with 93 ms for such a simple geometry!
It only filled triangles. But filling quads follows the same principle, just add one more repeat zone.
Since triangles have an odd number of edges (3), you won't create a triangle by going through the same edge twice/thrice e0 == e1, as it can't end up at the v0 this way.
When implementing quad support, you actually can create 0-area faces e0 == e1 == e2 == e3 or e0 == e3 and e1 == e2, but those will be removed by "Merge by Distance".
When implementing n-gon support, not only the complexity explodes and execution will take an eternity without optimization, but it's also not clear what the logic behind n-gons spawning should be. If you just spawn all possible n-gons, you will end up with a messs. Maybe you want to only spawn co-planar n-gons or have a threshold on acceptable deformation.
In 2D, you want to check the normals and flip faces with normals pointing down. In 3D space I have no idea.
In 2D there's probably much simpler/faster algorithms using raycasting.
You don't have to use repeat zones - it's just the simplest algorithm to show the logic... If this question becomes popular, I'll write a proper answer which is much faster and supports quads, cheers!



"Self-explanatory" ahem ... I'm still waiting for the nodes to explain themselves :P

Thank you! Let me try and will let you know.

@Markus von Broady, learning on this topic, is there any rule/way that can be used for weighting the order for this example? IMAGE and FILE aligning the radial gradient to constructed vector from edges at the point?

@filanek I think you just want to add another repeat zone to create quads

@Markus von Broady, no repeat zone here at all, in the image both versions are already created quads on the pure edge skeleton, left with the default indices from remaining sphere topology, right I mixed the indices randomly to show this method does not work in all cases. It needs some clever weight input if there any exists... Maybe this is just a blind way doing this....
